# Entity Framework, multiple one to many relationships based on column value

Tags: entity-framework-core

In an entity I'm trying to create multiple one-to-many relationships to the same child entity where the value of a column in the joining entity is different.

Here is a snippet of the entity I'm working with;

```
public class Forum
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public ForumType Type { get; set; } // Options are FORUM or GROUP
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Forum> Groups { get; set; } // Child forums with ForumType = GROUP
    public ICollection<Forum> Forums { get; set; } // Child forums with ForumType = FORUM
    public int Position { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
}
```

`ForumType` is an enum with two values of either `FORUM` or `GROUP`. I want the collections for `Group` or `Forums` to be based on the value of the `ForumType` column.

The property `Groups` will contain a list of all child forums where the value of `ForumType` is `Group`.
The property `Forums` will contain a list of all child forums where the value of `ForumType` is `Forum`.

I'm assuming I need to use the Fluent API to do this, but I can't seem to find how to do it.

UPDATE:

I want to provide a little more information to make it more clear what solution I'm looking for. Essentially, I'm looking for a final `Forum` table structure like this;

```
Id
Name
ForumType (0 = FORUM, 1 = GROUP)
ParentForumId
```

When building the relationships, I want the contents of the `Forums` collection to use a query such as;

```
SELECT * FROM Forums WHERE ParentId = {forumId} AND ForumType = 0
```

and when pulling in the groups, I'd like;

```
SELECT * FROM Forums WHERE ParentId = {forumId} and ForumType = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `HasMany` in your DatabaseContext `OnModelCreating` method or your entity configuration:

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Forum> Forums { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Forum>().HasMany(p => p.Forums);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Forum>().HasMany(p => p.Groups);
    }
}
```

and then use these codes to insert data:

```
var forum = new Forum(ForumType.Group)
{
    Groups = new List<Forum> { new Forum(ForumType.Group), new Forum(ForumType.Group) },
    Forums = new List<Forum> { new Forum(ForumType.Forum), new Forum(ForumType.Forum) }
};
context.Forums.Add(forum);
context.SaveChanges();
```

and these for read data:

```
var forum = await context.Forums
                .Include(c => c.Forums)
                .Include(c => c.Groups)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == yourId));
```

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't solve the problem as the one-to-many relationship doesn't know what I want to filter by the value of a column

Comment: You don't need any filter. When inserting data , you should just use correct collection. For example when you want to add new Forum with type Group , you should use Groups collection.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your requirement correctly. I read your question several more times and I guess you should use Global Query Filters. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters

Comment: I have updated my original question to hopefully make it more clear.